# Is there a specific order to the Colliders that Physics.OverlapSphere() returns?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a specific order to the Colliders that Physics.OverlapSphere() returns? (e.g. by proximity)

Unity Docs give no indication -

> Returns an array with all colliders touching or inside the sphere.

I also found this [Unity forum topic](https://answers.unity.com/questions/209488/does-overlapsphere-return-the-colliders-in-any-par.html), which states that there is no specific order, but the topic is from 2012 and doesn't seem to have had much attention so I wanted to check here.

Comment: *`I wasn't sure if anything had changed.`* Unlikely.

Comment: Physics engines use bounding volume hierarchies to optimize such queries, so the order would depend on those. But they are an internal detail of the physics engine. Sorting the colliders would be unnecessary in many cases, so it would waste performance. Therefore I sincerely doubt that they are sorted in any way

Comment: No, you would have to itterate through the overlap and find the closest

Comment: If it works, it probably wont be changed. If it barely works its at the bottom of the backlog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Afaik you can't rely on the order of physics in general. The order *might* depend on the order in the hierachy, not sure. But I'm quite sure it does **not** depend on proximity.

Something you could simply test ofcourse ;)

---

You could however simply sort them by proximity just to be sure using [Linq `OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby)

```
using System.Linq;

...

var colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(center, radius);
var orderedByProximity = colliders.OrderBy(c => (center - c.transform.position).sqrMagnitude).ToArray();
```

This sorts them at least roughly by ascending distance to their according GameObjects positions, which is perfectly fine if all the objects have the same size.

If you want the actual distance you would have to get creative and e.g. take their bounds into account.

Comment: Even if you test the queries and it does seem to return by distance, if the behavior is not documented then it is not guaranteed by Unity and should NOT be relied upon. The behavior could be changed in a future update without notice, or on a different platform, or literally whenever as it's just an implementation detail of the Unity's Engine. So if you need ordering by distance, then you need to sort.